# React native on android provides empty list when getting API JSON

Tags: android, json, react-native

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, TextInput, FlatList, Alert, StatusBar } from 'react-native';

//
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {live_score: [], firstTeam_VS_secondTeam: '', country_name: '', match_date: '', match_time: '', match_hometeam_name: '', match_hometeam_score: '', match_awayteam_name: '', match_awayteam_score: '', match_live: ''};
  }

  getLive_score = () => {
    const url = 'https://apifootball.com/api/?action=get_H2H&firstTeam=Chelsea&secondTeam=Arsenal&APIkey=ed96295659e2e5cf66df1306f844b7bb4a4018ae2baa153ba892cb17a8579001' + this.state.firstTeam_VS_secondTeam + '&country_name' + this.state.country_name + '&match_date=' + this.state.match_date + '&match_time=' + this.state.match_time + '&match_hometeam_name=' + this.state.match_hometeam_name + '&match_hometeam_score=' +  this.state.match_hometeam_score
    + '&match_awayteam_name=' + this.state.match_awayteam_name + '&match_awayteam_score=' + this.state.match_awayteam_score + 'match_live=' + this.state.match_live;
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => { 
     this.setState({Livescore: responseJson});


      })
      .catch((error) => { 
        Alert.alert(error); 
      });    
  }



  listSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 1,
          width: "80%",
          backgroundColor: "#CED0CE",
          marginLeft: "10%"
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar hidden={true} />
        <FlatList 
          style={{marginLeft : "5%"}}
          keyExtractor={match => match.id} 
          renderItem={({match}) => <Text style={{fontSize: 18}}>{match.firstTeam_VS_secondTeam}</Text>} data={this.state.Livescore} 
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.listSeparator} /> 
        <Text style={{fontSize: 18, width: 200}} placeholder='Country name' onChangeText={(country_name) => this.setState({country_name})} />
        <Text style={{fontSize: 18, width: 200}} placeholder='Match date' onChangeText={(match_date) => this.setState({match_date})} />
        <Text style={{fontSize: 18, width: 200}} placeholder='Match time' onChangeText={(match_time) => this.setState({match_time})} />
        <Text style={{fontSize: 18, width: 200}} placeholder='Hometeam name' onChangeText={(match_hometeam_name) => this.setState({match_hometeam_name})} />
        <Text style={{fontSize: 18, width: 200}} placeholder='Hometeam score' onChangeText={(match_hometeam_score) => this.setState({match_hometeam_score})} />
        <Text style={{fontSize: 18, width: 200}} placeholder='Awayteam name' onChangeText={(match_awayteam_name) => this.setState({match_awayteam_name})} />
        <Text style={{fontSize: 18, width: 200}} placeholder='Awayteam score' onChangeText={(match_awayteam_score) => this.setState({match_awayteam_score})} />
        <Text style={{fontSize: 18, width: 200}} placeholder='Live score' onChangeText={(match_live) => this.setState({match_live})} />
        <Button title="Hae ottelu tulokset" onPress={this.getLive_score} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the DATA from the API site
    {
    "firstTeam_VS_secondTeam": [{
        "match_id": "248036",
        "country_id": "169",
        "country_name": "England",
        "league_id": "70",
        "league_name": "Capital One Cup",
        "match_date": "2018-01-24",
        "match_status": "FT",
        "match_time": "21:00",
        "match_hometeam_name": "Arsenal",
        "match_hometeam_score": "2",
        "match_awayteam_name": "Chelsea",
        "match_awayteam_score": "1",
        "match_hometeam_halftime_score": "1",
        "match_awayteam_halftime_score": "1",
        "match_live": "1"
    },

Changing 'this.setState({Livescore: responseJson});' provides me withan invariant violation: tried to get frame for out of range index nan

So basically it provides me with an empty list, even tough the API site contains JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `data` props for the `FlatList` component as Object instead of array.

So it should have to be like in your render method.

```
  <FlatList 
          data = {this.state.Livescore}
          style={{marginLeft : "5%"}}
          keyExtractor={match => match.id} 
          renderItem={({match}) => <Text style={{fontSize: 18}}>{match.country_name}</Text>}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.listSeparator} />
```

And in response, you have to set your array value to the `live_score` in the state object.
So replace this :

```
     .then((responseJson) => { 
         this.setState({Livescore: responseJson});
     })
```

with below snippet:

```
.then((responseJson) => { 
       this.setState({Livescore: responseJson.firstTeam_VS_secondTeam});
  })
```

Hope this will help you.